# Hybris: add attributes to product via Impex

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I have a product catalog and a classification catalog. The product catalog contains a product and the classification catalog contains attributes, however when I try to insert the product with the attributes it doesn't show when I click the product and go under attributes tab.

How I enter product with attributes:

```
$lang=en
$productCatalog=productCatalog
$catalogVersion=catalogversion(catalog(id[default=$productCatalog]),version[default='Staged'])[unique=true,default=$productCatalog:Staged]
$approved=approvalstatus(code)[default='check']
$baseProduct=baseProduct(code,$catalogVersion)
$clAttrModifiers=system='MySystemClassifications',version='General',translator=de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.classification.impex.ClassificationAttributeTranslator,lang=nl
$id=@id[$clAttrModifiers];


INSERT_UPDATE Product;code[unique=true];$id;$catalogVersion
;M300047;200.59;
```

Is there something I have to do after adding it to link it to the product?

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of pitfalls when working with the classification system. I cannot see an obvious error in your impex script, so I want to ask for every precondition, that has to be fulfilled.

1. You need a ClassificationSystem (equivalent for Catalog for categories and product)
2. You need a ClassificationSystemversion (equivalent for CatalogVersion for category and product)
3. Your product has to be in a category.
4. This category needs a super category of type ClassificationClass.
5. You need a ClassificationAttribute.
6. You need a ClassAttributeAssignment which assigns your ClassificationAttribute to a ClassificationClass.
7. (Optional) You can create ClassificationAttributeUnits to define the unit of an attribute.
8. (Optional) You can create ClassificationAttributeValues to define possible values for a ClassificationAttribute.
9. When these preconditions are met, you can assign values to a product using your impex script.

Since this structure is a bit tricky, let me clarify it with an example:
Consider the ClassificationClasses "Photocameras" and "Videocameras". There are ClassificationAttributes like "Resolution", who are assigned to both ClassificationClasses using a ClassAttributeAssignment. But there might also be a ClassificationAttribute "Shutter Speed" assigned to only photocameras using a ClassAttributeAssignment. For photocameras shutter speed might be measured in milliseconds. So in the ClassAttributeAssignment for photocameras and shutter speed you assign a ClassificationUnit "milliseconds". Now consider a new ClassificationAttribute "Form Factor". There are only a few available form factors, so for each form factor you create one ClassificationAttributeValue. Using a ClassAttributeAssignment, you can assign an ClassificationAttribute "Form Factor" to your "Photocameras" ClassificationClass with the ClassificationValues "Compact Camera", "SLR" and so on. Once again, there might be different form factor values for video cameras.